# end-of-visual-line go to beginning of next line in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I want to use `beginneing-of-visual-line` and `end-of-visual-line`.

So I wrote in .emacs like following.

```
(global-set-key "\C-a" 'beginning-of-visual-line)
(global-set-key "\C-e" 'end-of-visual-line)
```

`beginning-of-visual-line` works as I hoped.
But if I use C-e in visually multiple lines, cursor go to the beginning of next line.

Why is this happens? And how can I fix it?

I'm using Emacs 24.3 (9.0) in Mac OS X 10.7.5.

Comment: Sounds like a bug you might like to `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: As Daniel explained the answer, I don't think this is a bug. But thanks for your info. I didn't know the `report-emacs-bug` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in general, `end-of-line` will position the point on the next character *after* the end of the line.

I find this helpful when coding in lisp, because it places the point in the perfect place to evaluate the previous s-exp easily.

However, in the case of end-of-visual line, the first character after the end of the line is actually on the next visual line. If you want the point to be on the last character of the current visual line, you could just go back one character, like this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-e") '(lambda ()
                               (interactive)
                               (end-of-visual-line)
                               (backward-char)))
```

**Edit**

A much better way of achieving the same thing - which will fix the point in your comment, is just to enable visual-line-mode:

```
(global-visual-line-mode 1)
```

This will automatically make your <kbd>C-a</kbd> and <kbd>C-e</kbd> work with visual lines.

The only problem with visual-line mode is that by default, there are no indicators showing where the line is wrapped. To fix this, you can use:

```
(setq visual-line-fringe-indicators '(left-curly-arrow right-curly-arrow))
```

You'll need to put the `visual-line-fringe-indicators` assignment before the `global-visual-line-mode` call in your .emacs for it to work.

Source for the above: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VisualLineMode

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Your code solved the problem that I asked. But I don't want to go back one character, if the visual line is only one. If it is _real_ end of line, I want to move cursor like `end-of-line`. How can I do it?

Comment: Edited my answer - visual-line-mode should sort this out. I did write  some elisp to do roughly the same thing - but I think it's best to use the built-in modes where possible.